# Rare physics edge case with 2D movement

Tags: c#, 2d, game-physics, physics

I'm building a space ship based game and I have an intermittent issue where my Force's sky rocket to infinity.  I'm assuming the issue is related to these relation ships:

- Acceleration depends on Force
- Velocity depends on Acceleration
- DragForce (Force) depends on Velocity

Here's the ship game: http://shootr.signalr.net

And here's a re-factoring (to make it not as large, combined some functions down) of the physics equation behind the movement.

```
double PercentOfSecond = (DateTime.UtcNow - LastUpdated).TotalMilliseconds / 1000;

// Mass = 50
_acceleration += Forces / Mass;

Position += Velocity * PercentOfSecond + _acceleration * PercentOfSecond * PercentOfSecond;
Velocity += _acceleration * PercentOfSecond;

_acceleration = new Vector2();
Forces = new Vector2();

// DRAG_COEFICCIENT = .2,  DRAG_AREA = 5
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Rotation), // Calculates the normalized vector to represent the rotation
        dragForce = .5 * Velocity * Velocity.Abs() * DRAG_COEFFICIENT * DRAG_AREA * -1;

Forces += direction * ENGINE_POWER; // Engine power = 110000

LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Comment: I don't see where your update `LastUpdated`... which would mean that `PercentOfSecond` will keep growing and growing...

Comment: Sorry that is Updated at the end of each iteration.  i'll update the code sample

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your bug playing with the live game you linked.  Can you give me a quick explanation of what bug you are seeing?

Comment: It only occurs in stress tested scenarios.  I've gotten it to repro with 300+ players.  Essentially the dragForce ends up increasing at a drastically high rate (on occassions) which then increases the acceleration which then increases the velocity and then it just infinitely loops in that cycle till the forces/velocity/acceleration go to infinity.

Comment: It sounds to me like latency is your problem. What happens to your equations when `PercentOfSecond`is very large? If it IS the drag force, does your problem go away if you turn off all drag forces?  (I'm sure you know this, but there are no drag forces in space.)

Comment: Thankfully when Percent Of second is very large it doesn't negatively affect the equations because it just moves the objects further, not faster based on the same period of time.  As for if I remove the drag force I then accelerate infinitely =(.  My hopes for the drag force was to alleviate the infinitely growing acceleration.

Comment: I think I see the problem. Which would you rather do, reduce the time interval (`PercentOfSecond`), or put in more complicated equations for more realistic motion?

Comment: I'd say more complicated equations are always ok =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have an inappropriate operation which will only work if you assume the vectors are initialized to the zero vector. eg:

```
_acceleration += Forces / Mass; // your code
_acceleration = Forces / Mass; // what it should be
```

Your Forces should also be:

```
Forces = direction * ENGINE_POWER + dragForce;
```

If that does not help with your problem, then you have issues with the calculation of the direction vector. Ensure that it is normalized. Your dragForce equation looks fine. However, make sure you add it and not subtract as you have already multiplied dragForce by -1.